How to Set Up an Alert for Monthly Median Latency Exceeding a Threshold in Sumo Logic?
I need to monitor the median latency of a specific API route in my service and set up an alert if the monthly median exceeds a defined threshold. For instance, consider the following example log entries:
PUT /route/A took 33ms and returned 200
PUT /route/A took 77ms and returned 200
.
.
.
.
.
PUT /route/A took 60ms and returned 200

I have a Key Performance Indicator (KPI) that states the monthly median (P50) for PUT /route/A should not exceed 67ms. I want to compute the median latency for each month and trigger an alert if the median exceeds this threshold.
Here is the query I am using in Sumo Logic to calculate the median:
service=myAwesomeService
| parse "PUT /route/A took *ms and returned 200" as latency_ms
| pct(latency_ms, 50) as median
| where median > 67

While the query works for calculating the median, I want to set up an alert that triggers if the monthly median exceeds 67ms. The issue is that Sumo Logic's alerting seems to be based on the number of results rather than the value of a specific field like median.
How can I configure Sumo Logic to trigger an alert based on the monthly median latency exceeding 67ms? If possible, please provide an example query and the steps needed to set up this alert.
